# Error when calling test file in h2o.predict function

Tags: r, data-science, h2o

prediction_h2o <- h2o.predict(automl_leader, testing)
when executing this syntax i got some weird error.

```
prediction_h2o <- h2o.predict(automl_leader, testing)

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Actual column must be integer class labels!

    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Actual column must be integer class labels!
        at hex.GainsLift.init(GainsLift.java:51)
        at hex.GainsLift.exec(GainsLift.java:124)
        at hex.glm.GLMMetricBuilder.makeModelMetrics(GLMMetricBuilder.java:217)
        at hex.glm.GLMModel.predictScoreImpl(GLMModel.java:1456)
        at hex.Model.score(Model.java:1381)
        at hex.ensemble.StackedEnsembleModel.predictScoreImpl(StackedEnsembleModel.java:150)
        at hex.Model.score(Model.java:1381)
        at water.api.ModelMetricsHandler$1.compute2(ModelMetricsHandler.java:374)
        at water.H2O$H2OCountedCompleter.compute(H2O.java:1386)
        at jsr166y.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:468)
        at jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:263)
        at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:974)
        at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1477)
        at jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
    Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Actual column must be integer class labels!
```

Comment: Please make the question more reproducible according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Difficult for anyone to meaningfully provide a solution without knowing what `automl_leader` and  `testing` are? Are they R objects of class `list`? The error says columns must be integer labels so there's where I'd start with. Please edit your question to provide a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to check the type of the two objects you are passing to the `predict` function and verify that your target column which contains labels is of the type you want it to be. The error message indicates that the predict function was expecting a label column of type integer but got something else.

In addition, I would take a look at the AutoML code example in the [documentation](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/automl.html#code-examples) and verify that you are replicating the same steps before using the predict function.

Answer (score 0):

This **problem is related to the H2O version**. So try to downgrade (version 3.22.1.6):

```
# The following two commands remove any previously installed H2O packages for R.
if ("package:h2o" %in% search()) { detach("package:h2o", unload=TRUE) }
if ("h2o" %in% rownames(installed.packages())) { remove.packages("h2o") }

# Next, we download packages that H2O depends on.
pkgs <- c("RCurl","jsonlite")
for (pkg in pkgs) {
if (! (pkg %in% rownames(installed.packages()))) { install.packages(pkg) }
}

# Now we download, install and initialize the H2O package for R.
install.packages("h2o", type="source", repos="http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-xu/6/R")

# Finally, let's load H2O and start up an H2O cluster
library(h2o)
h2o.init()
```

EDIT: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-tutorials/issues/107